# Pointer to integer conversion in Standard C

Tags: c, pointers, language-lawyer, c99, c11

I've read several questions in this web about this topic, but I still have doubts.

In Standard C we can read:

> 6.3.2.3.p.5: An integer can be converted to any pointer type. [...]
>   6.3.2.3.p.6: Any pointer type can be converted to an integer type. [...].

The omitted text (that would go in brackets [...]) just talks about the issues that could happen when conversion fails.

However my question is more general:

1. I observe that the **integer mathematical numbers** are infinite as a set of values.
2. Any integer type in C can represent only a finite subset of the integer mathematical values.
3. In paragraphs 6.3.2.3.p5/p6 it seems that **Standard C11** assumes that "every pointer value can be mapped to an **integer mathematical value**".
4. Besides, the way in that C11 standard is redacted seems to suggest that *only when this mathematical (or abstract) value cannot be represented in the intended integer type chosen by the developer*, for any reason, is when the operation fails.

**My question would be:** is my interpretation in point (3.) correct?

On the other hand, when we define an array of type *T* having size *N*,
since we can make integer arithmetic on the positions of the array,
it results obvious that, at least at "local" level, in an array,
we have that the corresponding block of memory of the array behaves
the same way, arithmetically, than the set of numbers from *0* to *N-1*, say.

By defining arrays or allocated objects, we can be sure that, in C,
the memory addresses can be "locally" considered as arithmetically equivalent to a subset of integers.

However, this "local" behavior would not be enough to derive the conclusion
that the Standard C assumes a memory model whose memory addresses can be considered as part of "only one and the same set of integer numbers".

However, 6.3.2.3.p5/p6 seems to "suggest" this stronger assertion, although I'm not completely sure.

**An additional question could be bring more light:**

- Is open in standard C the possibility that two different valid pointers `p`, `q`, (that is: `p != q`), when converted to an integer type, the resulting integer values become **equal**.

Comment: What is an "integer non-mathematical value" in your eyes?

Comment: @cad: I am trying to distinguish the abstract set of values, which is infinite, and have certain formal properties, from the particular subset of values capable of being representable in a given integer type in C. The values intended to be "integers" in a given type behaves different than the mathematical "integers". For example, UINT_MAX+1 == 0 in unsigned int. The behaviour is different, so they are not "mathematical", but a close simulation.

Comment: I think you're waaay overthinking this. I just memorize that a pointer can be converted to a standard integer type, where only `uintptr_t` and `intptr_t` are guaranteed to be capable of holding its value.

Comment: How is any type "mathematical" then? As far as I can tell from your explanation, a purely "mathematical" type is capable of holding every possible integer value, which is impossible, as there is only a finite amount of memory available.

Comment: @cad: I'am not considering purely "mathematical" values as having a type in C. In the same way that one can say "the value (purely mathematical or abstract) 1 centillion is not representable in 64-bit unsigned long long type". This mode of language is talking about "mathematical" or "abstract" numbers only, without a type, but then a given type is described. I'm trying to dilucidate if this mode of discourse is the same in the paragraphs 6.3.2.5p.5/p.6, when talking about the issues of pointer-to-integer conversion.

Comment: Re your last question, two unequal 64-bit pointers can be equal when truncated to 32-bit integers.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's odd that you disregard parts of the standard as "just talks about the issues that could happen when conversion fails" when some of those are exactly the parts that address your question.

> 1. I observe that the integer mathematical numbers are infinite as a set of values.

True, but irrelevant.  The standard says "any pointer type can be converted to [any] integer *type*" (emphasis added).  It is referring specifically to a family of C data types, including, but not limited to, `int`.  The text you omitted from your quote makes clear that some integer types might not be able to represent the result.  In fact, it says "The result need not be in the range of values of *any* integer type" (emphasis added).

> 2. Any integer type in C can represent only a finite subset of the integer mathematical values.

True.

> 3. In paragraphs 6.3.2.3.p5/p6 it seems that Standard C11 assumes that "every pointer value can be mapped to an integer mathematical value".

No, as a matter of fact not.  Part of the text you omitted was that "the
result is implementation-defined" for conversion in both directions, with certain exceptions.  The implementation-defined behavior of such a conversion could be that the program exits.  I'd accept that the standard suggests that there may be a mapping or mappings such as you describe, but not that it assumes there is one.

> 4. Besides, the way in that C11 standard is redacted seems to suggest that only when this mathematical (or abstract) value cannot be represented in the intedend integer type choosen by the developer, for any reason, is when the operation fails.

The operation never *fails*.  Under many circumstances the behavior is implementation-defined, and under some it is undefined, but that's altogether different.

Note, however, that the standard places more requirements on implementations that choose to provide the optional `intptr_t` and/or `uintptr_t` types, as these support round-trip, value-preserving `void *` to integer type to `void *` conversions.  Such implementations (which are typical) must have a 1-1 mapping from all possible pointer values not only to mathematical integers but to representable integer values.

Comment: Thank you John, by I'm trying to understand if the standard C considers the memory arithmetically as being similar to a unique subset of integers, or it's open to more extrange possibilities. On the other hand, I'm sorry if I'm not clear in my own question, but obviously this is part of my problems in understanding the topic in general.

Comment: Re. (3), "the result is i-d" --> "the result is i-d or UB"  . Re (4), it's normal to describe causing UB as "failing"

Comment: @pablo1977, the bottom line is "no", the standard itself does not consider (nor speak directly to) how memory addressing might map to integers.  It is common, however, for *implementations* to model memory via a flat address space that does map directly to integers, and that may even have the same representation as one of the system's integer types.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Thank you, John.

Comment: If the "result" is implementation-defined then the program would not exit.  That would be possible if the "behavior" were implementation-defined.

Comment: @DietrichEpp, the standard is not clear as to whether "the result" means "the resulting value" or "the resulting behavior".  I have taken the latter, more permissive interpretation.  I attribute it a quality of implementation detail that the program should not exit under such circumstances, not a requirement of the standard.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: With due respect, that reading is inconsistent with the surrounding language.  In the section, the "result" refers to a value, not a behavior.  For example: "If the *result* cannot be represented in the integer type, the *behavior* is undefined."  So it makes a distinction between "result" and "behavior".  Emphasis mine.  In the previous paragraph, "...the result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, ..., might be a trap representation..." A value can be a trap representation, but a behavior cannot.  Therefore the "result" is a value, not a behavior.

Answer (score 2):

> My question would be: is my interpretation in point (3.) correct?

The standard specifies the types `uintptr_t` and `intptr_t` such that each valid pointer can be converted to an `uintptr_t` / `intptr_t` and back again. Compare ISO 9899:2011 §7.20.1.4:

> #### 7.20.1.4 Integer types capable of holding object pointers
>
> 1 The following type designates a signed integer type with the property that any valid pointer to void can be converted to this type, then converted back to pointer to void, and the result will compare equal to the original pointer:
>
> ```
> intptr_t
> ```
>
> The following type designates an unsigned integer type with the property that any valid pointer to void can be converted to this type, then converted back to pointer to void, and the result will compare equal to the original pointer:
>
> ```
> uintptr_t
> ```
>
> These types are optional.

These types may not exist though, in which case no guarantee exists that each pointer maps to an integer.

> Is open in standard C the possibility that two different valid pointers p, q, (that is: p != q), when converted to an integer type, the resulting integer values become equal.

Yes, this can happen. Consider a platform like 8086 with 20 bit pointers and 16 bit `int`. Obviously, when converting pointers to integers, many pointers are going to be mapped to the same integer. If you take a larger type, like a 32 bit `long`, then you get a unique value for each pointer though.

Comment: Mmm. I can read in the standard that these integer types you mention, are optionally defined. This is the reason why I don't mention them in the question. (In standard C11: 7.20.1.4).

Comment: Note that `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t` are *optional*.  A C implementation can conform to the standard without providing them, nor indeed any type at all that can serve as they are described to do.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Try to refresh the page, I added a remark about this a couple of minutes ago.

Comment: "Obviously, when converting pointers to integers, many pointers are going to be mapped to the same integer." - not necessarily, some of the pointers may cause a hardware exception or cause the program to exit when the attempt is made to convert them to integer

Comment: @M.M Not for valid pointers and definitely not on 8086 (which is why I chose this concrete example).

Comment: "get a unique value for each pointer though." --> true.  Note that pointers that compare equally may covert to `intptr_t` and have those integer values _not_ compare equally.

Comment: @chux Huch? I'd like to have a source for this.

Comment: @FUZxxl invalid pointers may  not be evaluated anyway, and valid pointers may still cause UB on attempt to convert to integer

Comment: @M.M Invalid pointers may be evaluated if they point one past the end of an array.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your `p != q` question is given in the [...] part of paragraph 6:

> If the result cannot be represented in the integer type, the behavior
>   is undefined.

Hence, if `p` and `q` are two different valid pointers, and you convert those pointers to integers **without invoking undefined behavior**, then the resulting integers will not compare equal.

---

The answer to your main question is given in note 67 (which applies to paragraph 5):

> The mapping functions for converting a pointer to an integer or an
>   integer to a pointer are intended to be consistent with the addressing
>   structure of the execution environment.

In every execution environment that I'm aware of, the addressing structure is based on a finite subset of the natural numbers, with 0 being used as the `NULL` pointer. So converting from a pointer to an integer type is guaranteed to succeed if the range of integer values exceeds the range of addresses being used in the target hardware.

Comment: So, if we invoke **undefined behaviour**, we can have, for example, `(unsigned long)p == (unsigned long) q`, even in the case that `p!=q` (being p. q, pointers).

Comment: Yes but `unsigned long` *could* be the same size as the pointer.

Comment: Yes, but if you invoke undefined behavior, then anything can happen, e.g. your computer catches on fire. Programs that invoke undefined behavior are not useful.

Comment: Yours is a reasonable expectation, but not required by the standard.  Many conversions from pointer to integer involve *implementation-defined* behavior, as opposed to undefined behavior.  That implementation-defined behavior does not have to be what you describe.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I believe I addressed your concerns with the predicate *"In every execution environment that I'm aware of..."*. To some extent, the C language is a practical engineering construct, not just an arbitrary academic exercise.

Comment: "then the resulting integers will not compare equal."  - this is not a requirement of the standard -- only the footnote text (which is non-normative) suggests that it's useful for implementations to try and achieve that